# geopoint data not showing on Kibana Security map

Tags: security, elasticsearch, maps, kibana, geopoints

I wanted to show the geolocation of my source.ip data on a map.
I added a geoIP processor to my ingestion pipeline with target field `source.geo`, so now I get a field `source.ip.location`.

Initially, I mapped `source` in dynamic templates in the index mapping, but the field type was not being recognized (it showed in Kibana Discover with a question mark next to it). So I added the following manual mapping to the index:

```
"source": {
   "properties": {
       "ip": {
            "type": "ip"
        },
       "geo" :{
            "properties": {
                "region_iso_code":{
                    "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "country_iso_code":{
                    "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "location":{
                    "properties":{
                         "lat" : {
                             "type" : "long"
                          },
                         "lon" : {
                             "type" : "long"
                          }                          
                     }
                    "type" : "object"
                }
            },
            "type" : "object"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
},
```

This made the field type appaer as a number in Kibana Discover/Visualize, however, it still didn't appear on Kibana's Security.Network Map.

Then I added source to the index template, and set the location as a geo-point type.

```
"source": {
   "properties": {
       "ip": {
            "type": "ip"
        },
       "geo" :{
            "properties": {
                },
                "region_iso_code":{
                    "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "country_iso_code":{
                    "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "location":{
                    "type" : "geo_point"
                }
            },
            "type" : "object"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
},
```

When the index rolled over to the next one, the `source.ip.location` started to appear in Kibana's Discover with a red alert sign next to it, saying "analysis is not available for object fields". Needless to say, it still doesn't appear on the map, and now I have a conflict on the map's layer settings:

```
Data source: Documents
Index pattern: my_index_name
Geospatial field: source.geo.location
Geospatial field: type conflict
```

Any suggestions on how to get the geo_point data on the map?